# Request Permission To Access Contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, private, privacy

How can you setup an app that will ask for permission to access contacts before pulling up the Mail Composer? I know it is fairly recent that apps will do this.

Comment: If you're asking about things that have changed in iOS6, NDA requires that you discuss this only on the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: As far as I can tell, he was asking about the trend of apps asking for permission before accessing personal information such as in FourSquare after companies got busted for sending phone numbers, email addresses, etc to webservers without the explicit permission of users(Path is a great example of this but there were others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apple provides the `MFMailComposeViewController` it already has access to the users contacts built in, no need to have access granted. If you're looking to use the users contacts elsewhere you should look into the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example since I do not know what you are planning to do. You have a UIButton that reads "Access Contacts." When they click the button, you have the button run a method...Let's call it generatePopover. Well generatePopover should create a UIPopOverController with a statement on it asking for permission to access contacts. This view will have two buttons on it, accept and decline. Decline does nothing, where accept allows you to go ahead and pull up the mail controller.

Here's a link to the popover controller page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
//Header (.h)
@interface yourClass : superClass <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL alertShown;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL permissionGranted;

//Implementation (.m)
@synthesize alertShown, permissionGranted;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(buttonIndex == 1){

        self.permissionGranted = YES;
    }
    /*If you weren't sure what index the "Yes" button was at, you could do this instead:
    if(buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex){

        self.permissionGranted = YES;
    }
    Or this:
    if([buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){

        self.permissionGranted = YES;
    }*/
}

-(void)composeMail{
    if(!self.alertShown){

         UIAlertView *permissionsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission"
                                                              message:@"Permission to access contacts?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: @"Yes"];
        [permissionsAlert show];
    }
    if(self.alertShown && self.permissionGranted){

        //access mail/contacts
    }
}
//viewDidLoad
self.alertShown = NO;
self.permissionGranted = NO;
```

I just typed this out without checking or looking up anything, so there may be a mistake somewhere.
Anyway, hope this helps!